# Can't use data in template's @foreach anymore

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I've got a controller exposing object-data to a view:

```
$artifacts = Artifact::with('product');
return View::make('index', compact('artifacts'));
```

This used to work fine until last week. For some reasons now I can't use the data anymore in the template itself.

```
//this works
<?php
    print_r($artifacts->first());
?>

//this doesnt
@foreach ($artifacts as $artifact)
<?php 
    print_r($artifact);
?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using eager loading, you need to *get* the actual resultset.

```
$artifacts = Artifact::with('product')->get();
```